# How to test if an expression is a proper lvalue without changing its value?

Tags: r

I write some script, that act as a middle man between user and the R session. User inputs two fields: `lvalue` and `expression` with intention of executing `lvalue<-eval(parse(text=expression))`. Among other things the script needs to do, is to verify, that in this actual assignment the `lvalue` is a proper lvalue **without doing the actual assignment**.

Is it possible?

I want to make sure, that there are **no side effects whatsoever** after checking it (think about stream handlers, where assignments could have a lot of side effects).

I understand, that I can only be 100% sure the assignment worked only after it has be actually made; but can I do anything better than testing the proper evaluation of `eval(parse(text=lvalue))` (`lvalue` is input as string)?

I want to catch cases, when user supply a `lvalue` in the form of

- `incorrect-var-name`
- <s>`function(call)`</s>
- sin(x)

But I want the test to pass stuff like:

- `variable[indexing]`
- `double[[brackets]]`
- `even[complex[indexing]]`

---

update: [I asked a much narrower version of this question: How to test, if the given object `foo` has a assignment operator defined, so `foo<-value` has a chance to success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327462/how-to-test-if-the-given-object-foo-has-a-assignment-operator-defined-so-fo).

Comment: Can you show an example? Why not to assign to new variable and check if `lvalue` equal to `new_lvalue`?

Comment: @m0nhawk Unfortunately I prefer not to do that; otherwise I wouldn't ask. I've updated the question.

Comment: Setup a new environment for the testing and do all the checking/operations in there. No side-effects will occur in the current environment.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think, that there is a bunch of objects, that behave more like singletons, rather then "normal R objects" so the environments wouldn't jail them enough - I am thinking about the standard file handlers.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - I think I like the new formulation of this question better.

Comment: Both your negative cases **are** actually assignable: the first may be an invalid R name, but that’s just a syntactical hurdle. The second works if the user has `function<-` defined appropriately. So the situation is even more complicated.

Comment: @KonradRudolph when I make an assignment like `foo-bar<-42` the R interpreter complains with `could not find function "(<-"`; I have an impression, that the best I can do is to check, whether the `lvalue` object has a function `<-`