# How to test, if the given object `foo` has a assignment operator defined, so `foo<-value` has a chance to success?

Tags: r

Suppose I am given an unknown R object given `obj`.

I want to do a quick check (i.e. non-definitive) to see, if an assignment `obj<-value` has a chance to success, i.e. to see if there is a function `<-` defined for such assignment.

Is it possible to do it **without performing the actual assignment** in R?

Comment: I don't think your question makes any sense, as "success" has little meaning here.  In almost all cases, the "value" will override whatever previous "obj" existed -- not just it's `class` but the object itself.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft True; but what if the object is a scalar? It doesn't make sense to do `3<-5` does it? I want to trap these types of errors.

Comment: You couldn't make `3` an object name anyway unless you put it in backticks

Comment: @RichardScriven that's right; and these are the problems I want to trap; how to trap them without attempting to do the actual assignment?

Comment: I'm a bit late, but what about making a copy of `obj` and try-catching an assignment to it? Original `obj` would be intact then.

Comment: @tonytonov thank you. It is not too late. I suspect that the copy of the stream object is still pointing to the same string, so assigning to the copy would still do something to the stream. I didn't check it.

Comment: Indeed. Can you think of an illustration to the problem? It would be easier to approach the specific use case.